# sbt test run exits with 255

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Running the it:test suit which has docker kafka/zookeper/SR running we're seeing this error at the end of the test run:

```
sbt.ForkMain 50670 failed with exit code 255
```

Looking at the logs and tests they seem to pass just fine but still the total run is a failure in Jenkins eyes ofc. 
Increasing memory to sbt or underlying java didn't seem to yield any results.

Using sbt 1.3.8

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `sys.exit(-1)` was called from somewhere your test tear down code?

Comment: @cbley that was it in the depths of some dependencies, thank you :)